# Add carbon copy to completed DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a REST API method to add a carbon copy to a completed envelope? I'm able to achieve this in the Manage section of the DocuSign interface, selecting "Forward" on a completed envelope and adding a carbon copy recipient. Is there an API method to do the same thing?

Here's my scenario: currently we are using the REST API to send an envelope to 2 signers and then a carbon copy. We would like to halt the process between signer 2 and the cc, and only send the cc after an external event in our system. Is this possible through the API?

One possible alternative is to prevent the envelope from completing in the first place, by adding a dummy signer after signer 2 and before the cc, then deleting it when our event triggers. Ideally I'm looking for something simpler, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended technique for halting an envelope's progression is to add a dummy signer as you indicated. Then delete that signer to enable the envelope to continue.